# Code by Zapier - Input data field losing information when trying to execute code

Tags: zapier

I am using code by zapier, javascript.
I've used before and never had problems.
But today, as I am trying to create a new zap, I am reading data from trello and then trying to process the data with code by zapier.
I am filling data coming from trello in the field "Input Data", and then, trying to read the input data in my code using:

```
var cards = inputData['cards'].split(",");
```

The problem is that when I test the code, I receive an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

When I go to check the Input Data field, it is losing the information. 
Even if I type again, the Input Data information is not storing what I am asking there.

Any ideas?

Thank you
Amanda

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your zap setup? This error happens when `cards` is not present in the input

Comment: My bad for the wrong answer, you're absolutely right. I didn't think about the missing input first and it makes sense. I have deleted my post to prevent any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. I haven’t changed a thing.
I’ve tried in the next day with the same zap and that initial code that I posted.

Zapier was cleaning out the field with the data input from Trello (wasn’t detaining the value to pass to the next step).
Now it’s working. As I tried with different browsers on the same day and it was equally not working, I believe it was a bug that was fixed.